# Integrating an interesting improvement which is already rejected by the community

Tags: discussion, edits

When an edit is rejected by the community but you still believe it must be accepted, would you integrated the improvement yourself or would you comply to the decision of the community anyway?

Explanation:

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203095/display-window-full-screen-on-secondary-monitor-using-qt/16726611#16726611) is not very good. An [improvement](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15495607) was suggested. I accepted it but the community decided to reject it. I read both the question and answer, I still believe the suggestion is a big improvement upon the existing answer. Should I copy/paste that suggestion to the post anyway?

Comment: That edit is putting words (or rather, code) in the author's mouth. Really calls for a separate answer. Shows that maybe there's an education deficit, though - a separate answer would have been more beneficial for the user in every way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## No.

That user should have posted their own answer.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, but I read previously that post improvements are encouraged. I think the OP did the right thing: instead of repeating the same answer and add his own example, he added his example to improve an existing answer.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Improvements to fix spelling and grammar and the like are encouraged. Improvements to create new content out of thin air are not.

Comment: @RobertLongson Ok, I understand what you mean, thank you. But -sorry for the different question- what if the answer is outdated?

Comment: Outdated answers can still be useful when maintaining legacy software or working on old systems, which is sometimes unavoidable. If you have a better or more modern answer, you should post it as a separate answer. @Billal

Comment: If the answer is outdated, you can add a comment (or an edit/edit suggestion) saying "this answer refers to version X of product Y", and you can create an answer for the more current versions of the product.